# Import IFC in Revit using Forge (automatically generate ifc.rvt)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to automate the import of IFC file in Revit in order to automaticcally generate ifc.rvt files using Forge:

[AppBundle & Activity which I want to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW5X7.png)

```cs
private void ChangeIfcToRev(DesignAutomationData data)
{
    Application rvtApp = data.RevitApp;
    string modelPath = data.FilePath;
    Document doc = rvtApp.OpenIFCDocument(modelPath);
    ModelPath path = ModelPathUtils.ConvertUserVisiblePathToModelPath("result.rvt");
    doc.SaveAs(path, new SaveAsOptions());
}
```

Right now everytime I start my Plugin I get this error:

```
Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InvalidOperationException: The document can not be opened.
  at Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application.OpenDocumentFile(ModelPath modelPath, 
  OpenOptions openOptions)
  at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationData..ctor(Application revitApp, String 
  mainModelPath)
  at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationReadyEventArgs..ctor(Application revitApp, String 
  mainModelPath)
  at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationBridge.SetDesignAutomationReady(Application 
  revitApp, String mainModelPath)
  at RevitCoreEngineTest.RceConsoleApplication.Program.UserMain(CommandLineArgs cl)
```

Thats really weird because I dont use the `OpenDocumentFile` function in my code. Im using the `OpenIFCDocument` function.
Since I didn't get any further, I tried to only resave the ifc file. Same error.

Then I tried to use the samplePlugin from the Forge Tutorial:
https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/designautomation/appbundle/

The samplePlugin works fine with .rvt files but not with .ifc files. Also there I get an error.

What do I wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your activity and app bundle code as shared in the image look correct. Are you sure that is the activity used for this job? From the call stack in the exception it appears `/i \"$(args[rvtFile].path)\"` was used in the command line. Do you have a workitem id for an example failure?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, Forge DA for Revit insists on starting up Revit with an `RVT` input file argument provided. To work with this requirement, you might be able to provide a minimal **dummy** `RVT` file as an input argument and simply ignore it, continuing to open your `IFC` file as a **second** open document and saving that as `RVT` just like you are already doing now.

Looking more closely and the instructions to [Publish an Activity](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step5-publish-activity), I see that the input file is specified in the command line:

```
  "commandLine": [ "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[rvtFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[DeleteWallsApp].path)\"" ],
```

What input file are you specifying there?

Can you simply omit it?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the fast answear. Thats what Im using:

if (engine.Contains("Revit")) return new { commandLine = "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /al \"$(args[inputFile].path)\"", extension = "rvt", script = string.Empty };

Comment: Well, then, that is the answer. You are passing in a command line input argument. Maybe it is creating something like `revitcoreconsole.exe .rvt`. So, it is trying to open the file `.rvt`. You should try to specify zero arguments. Maybe simply by omitting both `$args` and `extension`. In your add-in, you can query the input arguments that were supplied to `revitcoreconsole.exe` and add them to your log to see what is going on. You can pass in [custom command line arguments to Revit.exe](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/01/face-methods-and-custom-command-line-arguments.html#2).

Comment: The devteam also replied: No, input rvt file is not required.
I think this customer assigns one ifc file in the '/i' argument in the commandLine, so DA4R open this ifc as rvt file, causing the error. (S)He  should not define '/i' argument in the commandLine of activity, and simply open ifc (e.g., "input.ifc") directly in the add-in.

Answer (score 0):

I heard back from the development team, and the solution is simpler still.

Just omit the input argument in your `commandLine` specification:

```
 "commandLine": [ "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /al \"$(appbundles[mybundles].path)\"" ]
```

This is not new, and most customers probably know it. Still, I agree we can update the Forge docs to explicitly state this usage.